# Shortcut for structure visualizer in Visual Studio 2017 (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I stumbled over the so called "structure visualizer" feature in Visual Studio 2017 and I like it a lot. This feature shows you the hierarchical structure of the file you are working on when you hover over one of the structure guidelines. See the picture for example:

[image]

My question now is, if there is a way to show this toolbox with a shortcut instead of hovering the mouse over one of these structure guidelines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default setting used `Ctrl+K, Ctrl+G`, but you can override it `Options > Keyboard`

[image]

Comment: Awesome, exactly what i was looking for! Thank you